# Sample browser code from Python for Everybody Chapter 12 lecture is not working as shown in the video

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming

I wrote the below code in Python (3) almost exactly as shown in the lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr9Vm-VghAk&list=PLlRFEj9H3Oj7Bp8-DfGpfAfDBiblRfl5p&index=51&t=0s

```
import socket

brows = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
brows.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
brows.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = brows.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
brows.close()
```

But when I run the program, it's unable to find the server and always returns the below shown output. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I'm a beginner to Python and am unable to see where it's going wrong. Please help. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem, and I found that the Py4e book, the slides on py4e.com, and the video lectures all had different variations of the code! The key to making it work was including "\r" in the cmd line:

cmd= 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()

The program worked for me after updating the code:)

Let me know if it works for you

Russ